# ¿Cual es el contentType correcto para JSON?

Tags: json

Veo que se pueden usar varios pero no entiendo sus diferencias o cuando debo usar uno u otro, por ejemplo:

```
    text/javascript
    text/x-javascript
    text/x-json
    application/json
    application/x-javascript
```

Comment: Esta es una pregunta traducida de: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según la sección 11 del [RFC7159: The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-11) el correcto es `application/json`:

```
11.  IANA Considerations

   The MIME media type for JSON text is application/json.

   Type name:  application

   Subtype name:  json
```

En el caso de las otras los usos son los sgtes:

- `text/javascript`. Está obsoleto, no lo uses
- `text/x-javascript` Era un content-type experimental, tampoco debe ser usado.
- `text/x-json` También experimental. No usarlo
- `application/x-javascript` Experimental al igual que los otros con prefijo `x-`. No usarlo

Además cabe mencionar que una alternativa que no es mencionada es `application/javascript`. Este content-type debe ser utilizado para *JavaScript* no confundirlo con *JSON*.

Comment: La respuesta más completa

Comment: Excelente respuesta gracias!

Comment: Gemasoft Si te sirvió esta respuesta puedes marcarla como aceptada

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Hasta donde conozco, si vas a transmitir JSON a través de un servicio HTTP, debebrías utilizar el content type `application/json` y está respaldado por el [protocolo estándar oficial de internet](http://www.rfc-editor.org/standards) [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Comment: Un comentario: el RFC 4627 fue dejado obsoleto por el RFC 7159 como puedes notar al comienzo del texto: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627. Es solo un comentario ya que esto no afecta la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Para `JSON` puro se debe usar `application/json` y para el caso de `JSONP` se debe usar `application/javascript`